# Haproxy - 301/302 redirect URL1 to URL2 with all pathes

Tags: redirect, haproxy, http-status-code-301, http-status-code-302

I'm a little bit lost atm. I try to implement a redirect within a complex HAproxy configuration. The goal is simple:

- user uses a subdomain -> 123.domain.com
- user will be pointed to api.domain.com but thinks it's still on 123.domain.com
- user should be able to use pathes like 123.domain.com/123?123 but still get results from api.domain.com/123?123 but thinks it's gets result from 123.domain.com/123?123.

I'm totally unsure how to implement that without taking the rist of taking down production traffic.

What i would do:

- creating ACL rule in SSL frontend to point to the api backend when 123.domain.de is used.

*redirect prefix http://123.domain.com code 301 if { hdr(host) -i api.domain.com }*

Not usre if that would work.

- creating redirection rule pointing simply to another api url:

*redirect location https://www.mysites/v2/pages 302 if { hdr(host) -i api.domain.com }*

It's hard to implement this wihtout taking a risk of an outage. Is there something who could know the answer?

Answer (score 1):

First I would recommend that you have a development and/or staging environment configured to test any changes before you make them.

To do a 301 redirect of all traffic coming from 123.domain.com to api.domain.com you can use the following

```
http-request redirect prefix http://api.domain.com code 301 if { hdr(host) -i 123.domain.com }
```

If you wanted HAProxy to connect to the api.domain.com backend on the users behalf and mask the hostname itself you would add a backend for api.domain.com and then create a `use_backend` rule.  Keep in mind that with the below there are no 301/302 redirects performed, instead HAProxy makes the connection on behalf of the client.

Something like this would work:

```
use_backend api.domain.com if { hdr(host) -i 123.domain.com }
```

Then within api.domain.com backend you can update the Host header.

```
backend api.domain.com
    http-request set-header Host api.domain.com
    server api1 api.domain.com:80 check
```

Comment: Thank you for answering so fast. I've created a docker-compose setup and with your solution i've got it to work. The domain kept still remains same. I figured out that your 2nd example is a shorter version as defining a acl rule before and the using the "use_backend" directive. I could also find out that when i'm using a map file it is the same as using your recommended use_backend solution. 

In Production:

The url does not remains the same. When i use 123.domain.com it points me to api.awin.com. What can i do to force that 123.domains.com will always shown up instead of api.domain.com?

Comment: No problem.  To clarify, it is working with 123.domain.com as you expect and now you want to add another subdomain like 345.domain.com?  If that's so you can just keep expanding the ACL on the use_backend line to include other hosts/subdomains.